# Mesh analysis in BJT circuits

Tags: circuit-analysis, bjt, education

Is it possible to use mesh analysis in BJT circuits? I tried to do it, but it does not work.

---

EDIT: the exercise in which the mesh analysis does not work is the following (the correct value of resistance is \$R_{E2}=640 \Omega\$).
Data: \$V_{CC}=12V, h_{FE}=100, I_{E1}=I_{E2}=0.002 A, R_{B1}=25467 \Omega, R_{B2}=74533 \Omega, R_{E1}=1000 \Omega, V_{BE,ON}=0.7V\$

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Of course it is. Mesh analysis has **nothing** to do with the type of components that are used.

Comment: Yes, but you will want to first convert the BJTs to their small signal equivalent circuits, consisting of resistors, caps, dependent sources.  From here it is more straightforward to solve using mesh analysis.

Comment: It does work. I actually had an epiphany once, when I worked a BJT circuit with both node and mesh... and got the same answer. That's when I realized I kinda knew what I was doing ;) keep at it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure! It's easier if you redraw the circuit to make the three-terminal BJT a pair of two-terminal components. You can do a large-signal analysis; it doesn't have to be small-signal.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fIRjYI.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Note that there's an extra unknown -- the voltage across the dependent current source. This is the collector-emitter voltage \$V_{CE}\$. To complete the analysis, you need an extra equation:

$$I_C = \alpha I_E = \frac {\beta}{\beta + 1} I_E$$

When \$\beta\$ is large,

$$I_C \approx I_E$$ (to within a few percent)

You might be tempted to go one step further and assume that \$I_B \approx 0\$. This would let you use a quick-and-dirty method for finding the bias point:

1. Calculate \$V_B\$ by treating the base bias resistors as a simple voltage divider.
2. Subtract 0.6V to get \$V_E\$.
3. Use \$V_E\$, \$R_E\$, and Ohm's Law to get \$I_E\$.
4. \$I_C\$ and \$I_E\$ are approximately the same, so now you have \$I_C\$ too.
5. Use \$I_C\$, \$R_C\$, and \$V_{CC}\$ to get \$V_C\$.

But this method only gives good results when the base resistors are small. (They usually aren't.) So it's better to include the base current in your analysis.

**UPDATE:**

In your schematic, you don't have loops for \$R_{C1}\$ and \$R_{C2}\$. You should have five loops total.

Let's go through the analysis of this circuit. I'll give the resistors some arbitrary values and assume \$\beta = 100\$.

$$-V_{CC} + (I_{CC} - I_C)R_{B1} + (I_{CC} - I_E)R_{B2} = 0$$
$$(I_E - I_{CC})R_{B2} + 0.6\mathrm{V} + I_E R_E = 0$$
$$(I_C - I_{CC})R_{B1} + I_C R_C + V_{CE} - 0.6\mathrm{V} = 0$$
$$I_C = \frac {\beta} {\beta + 1} I_E$$

Solving this gives:

$$I_{CC} = 5.272 \mathrm{mA}$$
$$I_E = 4.294 \mathrm{mA}$$
$$I_C = 4.251 \mathrm{mA}$$
$$V_{CE} = 1.455 \mathrm V$$

and from there, we can get:

$$I_B = I_E - I_C = 43 \mathrm {\mu A}$$
$$I_{RB1} = I_{CC} - I_C = 1.021 \mathrm{mA}$$
$$I_{RB2} = I_{CC} - I_E = 0.978 \mathrm{mA}$$
$$V_C = V_{CC} - I_C R_C = 5.749 \mathrm V$$

The only hard part is solving the system of equations. I use a TI-89 for this. On a networked computer, there are many other options.

Let's try this in the CircuitLab simulator with a \$\beta = 100\$ transistor and see what we get:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fbQtAi.png)</sup>

With this transistor (2N2222), the simulation results for \$I_C\$ and \$V_C\$ are within ~1% of our calculated values. Not bad!

Comment: Hi @Adam Haun, I tried to apply the mesh analysis on the circuit in the above figure, but the result is not correct. Could you suggest me what I did wrong? Thank you for your help.

Comment: @GennaroArguzzi I've updated my answer with some calculations.